# Two closed subsets $A$ and $B$ in $\mathbb{R}$ with $d(A,B)=0$

Tags: metric-spaces

I am looking for two closed subsets A and B (with $A\cap B = \emptyset$) of $\mathbb{R}$ with $d(A,B)=0$. I found a solution in $\mathbb{R}^2$, namely $A=\{(x,\frac{1}{x})\mid x>0\}$ and $B=\{(x,0)\mid x>0\}$. I know that those subsets have to be unbounded because there is a theorem that says: the distance between two closed subsets of which one is bounded, is greater than 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set $A=\mathbb{N}\setminus \{1\}$ and  $B=\{x+\frac{1}{x}:x\in A\}$

Comment: Isn't $\{x:x\in T\}$ simply $T$?

Comment: @celtschk, okay, if you like.

Answer (score 1):

I used one of your sets to give another example: $$A=\{(x,y)\mid xy\ge -1,x<0\},~~B=\{(x,y)\mid xy\ge1,x>0\}$$

[image]

Comment: Very nice graphs you draw. You must have a handy scanner? Or camera?

Comment: @amWhy: It is really a camera! 12 mega pix Canon

Comment: awesome! It does good work for you!